# Connect sequelize to mysql on MACOS using XAMP

Tags: node.js, macos, xampp, sequelize.js

I'm nex to using macos environment and i'm having trouble connecting sequelize to mysql server that's running on xamp

I'm able to open phpmyadmin dashboard through [localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/](https://ocalhost:8080/phpmyadmin/)
I can also CLEARLY SEE on XAMP that there's another IP address which is 192.168.64.2

### [image: xamp]

Here's my db.config

```
    HOST: process.env.HOST,
  USER: process.env.USER,
  PASSWORD: process.env.PASSWORD,
  DB: process.env.DB,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000,
  },
```

and my .env file contains these parameters

I have tried many alternatives such as

```
#mysql config Variables

HOST=localhost
USER=root
PASSWORD=
DB=cynoia
DIALECT=mysql`
```

#mysql config Variables

```
HOST=192.168.64.2
USER=root
PASSWORD=
DB=cynoia
DIALECT=mysql
```

I have even created a new user and tried to connect with his accesses

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But nothing to seems to work the error is always the same

access denied for user

```
Access denied for user 'imac'@'192.168.64.1' (using password: NO)
      at Packet.asError (/Users/imac/Documents/CYNOIA-back-main/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
      at ClientHandshake.execute (/Users/imac/Documents/CYNOIA-back-main/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (/Users/imac/Documents/CYNOIA-back-main/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/Users/imac/Documents/CYNOIA-back-main/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/Users/imac/Documents/CYNOIA-back-main/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/imac/Documents/CYNOIA-back-main/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
      at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9) {
    code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
    errno: 1045,
    sqlState: '28000',
    sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'imac'@'192.168.64.1' (using password: NO)",
    sql: undefined
```

I cannot seem to understand why it shows user 'imac' even though that's not the user i need and why it doesnt work simply on localhost
I'm a windows user it never happened to me before, can anyone provide any help ?

Comment: Show how you pass these connection parameters to Sequelize

Comment: It's in the question, i pass .env variables to my db.config the same exact code works on my widows PC when i cloned the code to my new MACOS it throwed this error .

Comment: I measn Sequelize expects lower case parameters and `username` instead of `user`. Or did I misunderstand you?